# How to Include a BOM(bill of material) as a child of the parent pom

Tags: maven, maven-bom

According to Maven documentation, BOM should be the parent of the parent-project.
However, I am following what [Resteasy](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy) does by including the BOM as the child pom of the parent-project.

Since the parent pom needs to have all the dependencies declared with version, I want to figure out a way such that I am able to remove all of the dependencies from my parent-pom and just have it in my BOM